# Select only some entries based on what's in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to grab all of the offers provided to a user that are not already queued up in their projects. So, I'm grabbing offers from the `OfferSuggestionHeader` table based on my user's ID but also try to make sure it doesn't grab anything that the user has already added to their projects (stored in the `Projects` table)

I've got the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ofh.OfferID, ofh.OfferTitle, ofh.OfferVendor, ofh.Savings,ofh.SavingsPercent
    FROM OfferSuggestionHeader ofh
LEFT JOIN OfferSuggestionDetail osd
    ON ofh.OfferID = osd.OfferID
LEFT JOIN Facilities f
    ON osd.FacilityID = f.id
LEFT JOIN UserFacility uf
    ON f.id = uf.fid
LEFT JOIN Users u
    ON uf.uid = u.uid
LEFT JOIN Projects p
    ON p.uid = u.uid
WHERE p.uid = '1' 
    AND ofh.OfferID <> ANY (SELECT offer_id FROM Projects WHERE uid = '1')
```

It pulls up all of the offers. If I take away `ANY` then I get an error saying that the subquery returns too many results.

There are 6 offers. Three are queued up by user 1. I shouldn't see offers 1, 4, or 5.

Thanks for any pointers and help.

Comment: you can try  <<AND ofh.OfferID NOT IN (SELECT offer_id FROM Projects WHERE uid = '1')>>

Comment: @John, this `SELECT offer_id FROM Projects WHERE uid = '1'` returns 6 offers under uid = 1. Does it mean offer IDs from `1,2,3,4,5,6`? And you also specified that you don't want offers `1, 4, 5`? So will it be easier for you to simply does `AND ofh.OfferID NOT IN (1, 4, 5)` given that you already have JOIN Projects table in the main query and `WHERE P.uid = 1` included...

Comment: Thanks, guys. You were both right. I had a moment of idiocy apparently. I tried `IN` in place of the `ANY` operation, but didn't think to add `NOT` which is now so obvious! @bonCodigo, I need to use the `SELECT` because me not wanting 1, 4, and 5 (out of 1-6) is only known because I'm dev'ing it, so the `SELECT` statement will stand in place of my 'omniscience' :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment explanation, why not try this? I am not sure why you need a subquery when you already have PROJECT table JOINED in your main query..

```
WHERE p.uid = '1' 
    AND ofh.OfferID NOT IN (1, 4, 5);
```